# How to select values from same column using different where statements - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, psql

I have the following code.

```
SELECT
 TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum,
 count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Total_Leads
FROM
 leads a
WHERE
 date(a.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-06-01'
 AND 'TODAY' 
 AND a.lead_delivery_time IS NOT NULL
 AND a.lead_filler IN ('Android', 'iOS', 'MobileWeb', 'Web')
GROUP BY 1
```

The above query provides monthly leads.

Then I have another query, which provides only "Rent" Leads.

```
SELECT
 TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum,
 count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Rent_Leads
FROM
 leads a
WHERE
 date(a.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-06-01'
 AND 'TODAY' 
 AND a.lead_delivery_time IS NOT NULL
 AND a.lead_filler IN ('Android', 'iOS', 'MobileWeb', 'Web')
 AND a.service IN ('Leads::Rent')
GROUP BY 1
```

Now I can create two separate queries, however I want both the values to be shown via a single query in the following format

Month -> Total Leads -> Rent Leads

I have tried using, join, union, subquery but not able to get the desired data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
SELECT t1.Datum AS Month, t1.Total_Leads AS Total, t2.Rent_Leads AS Rent 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum, count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Total_Leads
                     FROM leads a
                     WHERE date(a.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-06-01'
                     AND 'TODAY' 
                     AND a.lead_delivery_time IS NOT NULL
                     AND a.lead_filler IN ('Android', 'iOS', 'MobileWeb', 'Web')) AS x
      GROUP BY 1         
     ) AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(b.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum, count(distinct(b.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Rent_Leads
                           FROM leads b
                           WHERE date(b.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-06-01'
                           AND 'TODAY' 
                           AND b.lead_delivery_time IS NOT NULL
                           AND b.lead_filler IN ('Android', 'iOS', 'MobileWeb', 'Web')
                           AND b.service IN ('Leads::Rent')) AS y
            GROUP BY 1
           ) AS t2
ON t1.Datum = t2.Datum;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I also had tried the same query earlier in the dat but it was showing following error
ERROR:column "a.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: TO_CHAR is a custom function right? Try adding another `SELECT * ` outside the subquery to bypass the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum,
   count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Total_Leads,
   sum(case when a.service IN ('Leads::Rent') then 1 else 0 end) AS Rent_Leads
FROM leads a
WHERE date(a.created_at) BETWEEN '2017-06-01'
AND 'TODAY' 
AND a.lead_delivery_time IS NOT NULL
AND a.lead_filler IN ('Android', 'iOS', 'MobileWeb', 'Web')
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. However the above query is giving syntax error. 
Error: syntax error or at near "THEN"

Comment: Thanks again. The query is working, however rent leads are not coming out to be unique. Like in Total_Leads we did distinct, we need to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

An option I have used in this situation is to use union:

Use your first query as

```
SELECT
 TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum,
 count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Total_Leads, 0 as Rent_leads...
```

union this with your second as

```
SELECT
 TO_CHAR(a.created_at, 'YYYY.MM') AS Datum,
 0 as Total_Leads,
 count(distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)) AS Rent_Leads...
```

This works but means you effectively read the main table twice, an alternative is to use the fact that NULLS are not counted. I have assumed  lead_demand_user_id
 is a number. In Oracle you can use `Decode(a.service,'Leads::Rent',1,null)` to create either a 1 or null.then `count (distinct(a.lead_demand_user_id)*Decode(a.service,'Leads::Rent',1,null)) as Rent_Leads`
I'm not sure if Decode is available in other SQLs.

Hope this helps

Stephen L. Lee